# Drupal 7: View filters impact on performance

Tags: 7, views, performance

Does having multiple view filters affect the overall performance of the site. for example having a category and search filter on main pages of articles and galleries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general having more views will effect the performance of your site. However you can check the view query / render etc at the bottom of the view edit pages which should give you insights into what degree they effect performance. You can also cache views but it means there will be a lag on content updates being shown by the view.

In general you will also find more modules you add to drupal will have a performance impact although it could be slight. Even adding views to pages will add js and css and thus the more page weight so it will take longer to download. Also views run will have more db queries and have a performance impact on the database.

Was there something in particular you were looking for?

Comment: As for views filters, they'll of course only affect performance if used.

Comment: thanks guys.@WestieUK - i have a site with a lot of views filters so was wondering whether to leave them on or remove them. what if i add apache solr?

Comment: The amount of views or filters is not always a performance problem & you should weigh up the functionality / performance cost. Why do you think the views in particular are an issue? You should check all yours views performance to see if any stand out as being slow. If so you can play with the filters and caching to bring the query & render times down to acceptable levels. You may even need to apply an index in your db. If you are finding you site is running slow there is a great deal you can do with Drupal in terms of caching, compression or even by using tools like yslow to bench mark.