# How to show different entity in Views with different displays?

Tags: views

I create a views with 2 displays.

One display show **content type.**

One display show **taxonomy** list that related above content type.

When I try to create a display with content type, then I can not create a display with taxonomy.

Content type and taxonomy are different entity, So How to show different entity in Views with displays?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add relationships **Content: Taxonomy terms on node** then you will get options to add **taxonomy** in **filter criteria** and **fields**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are right, But not perfect, not friendly to performance

Comment: For performance you can check 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26745/drupal-7-view-filters-impact-on-performance